# How to implement homepage minicart qty increment and decrement option?

Tags: magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce

I want to implement the qty increment and decrement option in the mini cart on the homepage.

Comment: Could you describe what have you done so far?

Comment: I am tried this, but not working https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-quantity-increment-and-decrement-button-in-magento-2/?unapproved=12212&moderation-hash=67c05f28c69d8e1e5b4ac1ce368ab272#comment-12212

Comment: You have everything. If it's not working out of the box, you should check the flow to see where it get wrong.

Comment: If you checked the source code, read it, follow it and still don't understand, you can always post your question about the flow here.

Answer (score 1):

1)Create a file in Vendor\module\View\frontend\web\js\view\minicart.js and add following code:

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'sidebar',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/dropdown'
], function (Component, customerData, $, ko, _) {
    'use strict';

    var sidebarInitialized = false,
        addToCartCalls = 0,
        miniCart;

    miniCart = $('[data-block=\'minicart\']');

    /**
     * @return {Boolean}
     */
    function initSidebar() {
        if (miniCart.data('mageSidebar')) {
            miniCart.sidebar('update');
        }

        if (!$('[data-role=product-item]').length) {
            return false;
        }
        miniCart.trigger('contentUpdated');

        if (sidebarInitialized) {
            return false;
        }
        sidebarInitialized = true;
        miniCart.sidebar({
            'targetElement': 'div.block.block-minicart',
            'url': {
                'checkout': window.checkout.checkoutUrl,
                'update': window.checkout.updateItemQtyUrl,
                'remove': window.checkout.removeItemUrl,
                'loginUrl': window.checkout.customerLoginUrl,
                'isRedirectRequired': window.checkout.isRedirectRequired
            },
            'button': {
                'checkout': '#top-cart-btn-checkout',
                'remove': '#mini-cart a.action.delete',
                'close': '#btn-minicart-close'
            },
            'showcart': {
                'parent': 'span.counter',
                'qty': 'span.counter-number',
                'label': 'span.counter-label'
            },
            'minicart': {
                'list': '#mini-cart',
                'content': '#minicart-content-wrapper',
                'qty': 'div.items-total',
                'subtotal': 'div.subtotal span.price',
                'maxItemsVisible': window.checkout.minicartMaxItemsVisible
            },
            'item': {
                'qty': ':input.cart-item-qty',
                'button': ':button.update-cart-item',
                'qtyDecreasing': '.decreasing-qty',
                'qtyIncreasing': '.increasing-qty'
            },
            'confirmMessage': $.mage.__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?')
        });
    }

    miniCart.on('dropdowndialogopen', function () {
        initSidebar();
    });

    return Component.extend({
        shoppingCartUrl: window.checkout.shoppingCartUrl,
        maxItemsToDisplay: window.checkout.maxItemsToDisplay,
        cart: {},

        initialize: function () {
            var self = this,
                cartData = customerData.get('cart');

            this.update(cartData());
            cartData.subscribe(function (updatedCart) {
                addToCartCalls--;
                this.isLoading(addToCartCalls > 0);
                sidebarInitialized = false;
                this.update(updatedCart);
                initSidebar();
            }, this);
            $('[data-block="minicart"]').on('contentLoading', function () {
                addToCartCalls++;
                self.isLoading(true);
            });

            if (
                cartData().website_id !== window.checkout.websiteId && cartData().website_id !== undefined ||
                cartData().storeId !== window.checkout.storeId && cartData().storeId !== undefined
            ) {
                customerData.reload(['cart'], false);
            }

            return this._super();
        },
        //jscs:enable requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers

        isLoading: ko.observable(false),
        initSidebar: initSidebar,

        /**
         * Close mini shopping cart.
         */
        closeMinicart: function () {
            $('[data-block="minicart"]').find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog('close');
        },

        /**
         * @param {String} productType
         * @return {*|String}
         */
        getItemRenderer: function (productType) {
            return this.itemRenderer[productType] || 'defaultRenderer';
        },

        /**
         * Update mini shopping cart content.
         *
         * @param {Object} updatedCart
         * @returns void
         */
        update: function (updatedCart) {
            _.each(updatedCart, function (value, key) {
                if (!this.cart.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    this.cart[key] = ko.observable();
                }
                this.cart[key](value);
            }, this);
        },

        /**
         * Get cart param by name.
         *
         * @param {String} name
         * @returns {*}
         */
        getCartParamUnsanitizedHtml: function (name) {
            if (!_.isUndefined(name)) {
                if (!this.cart.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                    this.cart[name] = ko.observable();
                }
            }

            return this.cart[name]();
        },

        /**
         * @deprecated please use getCartParamUnsanitizedHtml.
         * @param {String} name
         * @returns {*}
         */
        getCartParam: function (name) {
            return this.getCartParamUnsanitizedHtml(name);
        },

        /**
         * Returns array of cart items, limited by 'maxItemsToDisplay' setting
         * @returns []
         */
        getCartItems: function () {
            var items = this.getCartParamUnsanitizedHtml('items') || [];

            items = items.slice(parseInt(-this.maxItemsToDisplay, 10));

            return items;
        },

        /**
         * Returns count of cart line items
         * @returns {Number}
         */
        getCartLineItemsCount: function () {
            var items = this.getCartParamUnsanitizedHtml('items') || [];

            return parseInt(items.length, 10);
        }
    });
});
```

2)Create a file in Vendor\module\View\frontend\web\js\sidebar.js and add following code:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/decorate',
    'mage/collapsible',
    'mage/cookies'
], function ($, authenticationPopup, customerData, alert, confirm) {

    $.widget('mage.sidebar', {
        options: {
            isRecursive: true,
            minicart: {
                maxItemsVisible: 3
            }
        },
        scrollHeight: 0,

        /**
         * Create sidebar.
         * @private
         */
        _create: function () {
            this._initContent();
        },

        /**
         * Update sidebar block.
         */
        update: function () {
            $(this.options.targetElement).trigger('contentUpdated');
            this._calcHeight();
            this._isOverflowed();
        },

        _initContent: function () {
            var self = this,
                events = {};

            this.element.decorate('list', this.options.isRecursive);

            events['click ' + this.options.button.close] = function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                $(self.options.targetElement).dropdownDialog('close');
            };
            events['click ' + this.options.button.checkout] = $.proxy(function () {
                var cart = customerData.get('cart'),
                    customer = customerData.get('customer');

                if (!customer().firstname && cart().isGuestCheckoutAllowed === false) {
                    // set URL for redirect on successful login/registration. It's postprocessed on backend.
                    $.cookie('login_redirect', this.options.url.checkout);
                    if (this.options.url.isRedirectRequired) {
                        location.href = this.options.url.loginUrl;
                    } else {
                        authenticationPopup.showModal();
                    }

                    return false;
                }
                location.href = this.options.url.checkout;
            }, this);
            events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                confirm({
                    content: self.options.confirmMessage,
                    actions: {
                        confirm: function () {
                            self._removeItem($(event.currentTarget));
                        },
                        always: function (event) {
                            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
            events['keyup ' + this.options.item.qty] = function (event) {
                self._showItemButton($(event.target));
            };
            events['click ' + this.options.item.button] = function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                self._updateItemQty($(event.currentTarget));
            };
            events['focusout ' + this.options.item.qty] = function (event) {
                self._validateQty($(event.currentTarget));
            };

            // The bellow codes will execute when you click on the decrease button
            events['click ' + this.options.item.qtyDecreasing] = function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                var itemId = $(event.currentTarget).data('cart-item');
                var qtyElement = $('#cart-item-'+itemId+'-qty');
                var qtyValue = parseInt(qtyElement.val());
                qtyValue = qtyValue - 1;
                if (qtyValue <= 0) {
                    qtyValue = 1;
                }
                qtyElement.val(qtyValue).trigger('keyup');
            };

            // The bellow codes will execute when you click on the increase button
            events['click ' + this.options.item.qtyIncreasing] = function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                var itemId = $(event.currentTarget).data('cart-item');
                var qtyElement = $('#cart-item-'+itemId+'-qty');
                var qtyValue = parseInt(qtyElement.val());
                qtyValue = qtyValue + 1;
                if (qtyValue > 100) {
                    qtyValue = 100;
                }
                qtyElement.val(qtyValue).trigger('keyup');
            };

            this._on(this.element, events);
            this._calcHeight();
            this._isOverflowed();
        },

        /**
         * Add 'overflowed' class to minicart items wrapper element
         *
         * @private
         */
        _isOverflowed: function () {
            var list = $(this.options.minicart.list),
                cssOverflowClass = 'overflowed';

            if (this.scrollHeight > list.innerHeight()) {
                list.parent().addClass(cssOverflowClass);
            } else {
                list.parent().removeClass(cssOverflowClass);
            }
        },

        _showItemButton: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item'),
                itemQty = elem.data('item-qty');

            if (this._isValidQty(itemQty, elem.val())) {
                $('#update-cart-item-' + itemId).show('fade', 300);
            } else if (elem.val() == 0) {
                this._hideItemButton(elem);
            } else {
                this._hideItemButton(elem);
            }
        },

        /**
         * @param origin - origin qty. 'data-item-qty' attribute.
         * @param changed - new qty.
         * @returns {boolean}
         * @private
         */
        _isValidQty: function (origin, changed) {
            return (origin != changed) &&
                (changed.length > 0) &&
                (changed - 0 == changed) &&
                (changed - 0 > 0);
        },

        /**
         * @param {Object} elem
         * @private
         */
        _validateQty: function (elem) {
            var itemQty = elem.data('item-qty');

            if (!this._isValidQty(itemQty, elem.val())) {
                elem.val(itemQty);
            }
        },

        _hideItemButton: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');
            $('#update-cart-item-' + itemId).hide('fade', 300);
        },

        _updateItemQty: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');
            this._ajax(this.options.url.update, {
                item_id: itemId,
                item_qty: $('#cart-item-' + itemId + '-qty').val()
            }, elem, this._updateItemQtyAfter);
        },

        /**
         * Update content after update qty
         *
         * @param elem
         */
        _updateItemQtyAfter: function (elem) {
            this._hideItemButton(elem);
        },

        _removeItem: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

            this._ajax(this.options.url.remove, {
                item_id: itemId
            }, elem, this._removeItemAfter);
        },

        /**
         * Update content after item remove
         *
         * @param {Object} elem
         * @private
         */
        _removeItemAfter: function (elem) {
            var productData = customerData.get('cart')().items.find(function (item) {
                return Number(elem.data('cart-item')) === Number(item['item_id']);
            });

            $(document).trigger('ajax:removeFromCart', productData['product_sku']);
        },

        /**
         * @param {String} url - ajax url
         * @param {Object} data - post data for ajax call
         * @param {Object} elem - element that initiated the event
         * @param {Function} callback - callback method to execute after AJAX success
         */
        _ajax: function (url, data, elem, callback) {
            $.extend(data, {
                'form_key': $.mage.cookies.get('form_key')
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: data,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                context: this,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    elem.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                },
                complete: function () {
                    elem.attr('disabled', null);
                }
            })
                .done(function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        callback.call(this, elem, response);
                    } else {
                        var msg = response.error_message;

                        if (msg) {
                            alert({
                                content: msg
                            });
                        }
                    }
                })
                .fail(function (error) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                });
        },

        /**
         * Calculate height of minicart list
         *
         * @private
         */
        _calcHeight: function () {
            var self = this,
                height = 0,
                counter = this.options.minicart.maxItemsVisible,
                target = $(this.options.minicart.list),
                outerHeight;

            self.scrollHeight = 0;
            target.children().each(function () {

                if ($(this).find('.options').length > 0) {
                    $(this).collapsible();
                }
                outerHeight = $(this).outerHeight();

                if (counter-- > 0) {
                    height += outerHeight;
                }
                self.scrollHeight += outerHeight;
            });

            target.parent().height(height);
        }
    });

    return $.mage.sidebar;
});
```

3)2)Create a file in Vendor\module\View\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\default.html and add following code:

```
<li class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
    <div class="product">
        <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <span class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-details">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
                <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: product_name"></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                    <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </strong>

            <!-- ko if: options.length -->
            <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && ['file', 'html'].includes(option.option_type)) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && !['file', 'html'].includes(option.option_type)) -->
                            <span data-bind="text: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div class="product-item-pricing">
                <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

                <div class="details-map">
                    <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                    <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                           <button type="button" data-bind="attr: {title: $t('Decrease the quantity'), 'data-cart-item': item_id, 'data-item-qty': qty}" style="background-color:#1979c3;color:#fffcff;" class="decreasing-qty">-</button>
                           <input data-bind="attr: {
                                  id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                                  'data-cart-item': item_id,
                                  'data-item-qty': qty,
                                  'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                                  }, value: qty"
                                  type="number"
                                  size="4"
                                  class="item-qty cart-item-qty"
                                  maxlength="12"/>
                           <button type="button" data-bind="attr: {title: $t('Increase the quantity'), 'data-cart-item': item_id, 'data-item-qty': qty}" style="background-color:#1979c3;color:#fffcff;" class="increasing-qty">+</button>
                    <button data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           title: $t('Update')
                           }"
                            class="update-cart-item"
                            style="display: none">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product actions">
                <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                <div class="primary">
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message notice" if="$data.message">
        <div data-bind="text: $data.message"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: After added it is not visible on mini cart,  file structure : https://snipboard.io/JRz9Qa.jpg

Comment: run command setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: php bin/magento c:f

Comment: php bin/magento c:c

Comment: chmod -R 777 var pub generated

Comment: kindly upvote my answer it is correct and working here

Comment: I did everything.

Comment: My file structure is correct, right?

Comment: but it works for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122486/discussion-between-zus-and-technerd).

Comment: Can u pls share ur screenshot?